# Manipulate the height of webkit-keyframes when height is 100%

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have webkit css below to animate my top-menu.I only want to control the height attribute(height:150px) by js,when its 100% which means max-height when its been opened.

```
 from {
    height:var(--m,0%);
}
```

Here's my CSS

```
@-webkit-keyframes expand{
    0%{height:0px}
    100%{height:150px}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the event `animationend`:
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_animationend.asp

```
    document.getElementById('yourselector').addEventListener('animationend', e=>console.log('animation ended'),false)
```